# Pytest AttributeError: 'TestMyTest' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pytest

I have multiple tests written in the following format. When the test is run, why do some tests fail with exception `AttributeError: 'TestMyTest' object has no attribute 'var1'`?

`var1` is defined as class variable in `test_init()`. Still the exception is thrown in `test_1()`.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def do_setup(run_apps):
    """
    Do setup
    """
    # Do something
    yield some_data


class TestMyTest(BaseTestClass):
    ids = dict()
    task_id = list()
    output_json = None

    def test_init(self, do_setup):
        TestMyTest.var1 = Feature1()

    def test_1(self):
        self._logger.info("self.var1: {}".format(self.var1))
```

Comment: Apparently `test_init()` was not called. Why do you think it should have been called before `test_1()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var1` was not defined as `test_init()` failed.